Japanese or Chinese movie with women fighting using needles and thread
I saw a Chinese movie around 2000/2005. I don't exactly remember the plot or story line but I remember the climax well. In the climax there is a fight between the villain and the lead actress who fights using only a needle and thread and the villain fights using the chain and hook like connected weapon. 
Sorry for this short description, but that's all I remember. Hope anybody might would have seen it. The movie might be around released somewhere between 1991-1998.

That might indeed be too short, so I voted to close it... But thanks for coming back. This is probably what you're looking for.

Walt's suggestion sounds like a good possibility, but I was (coincidentally) thinking of another Jet Li film myself:
Legend of the Red Dragon



This video shows the needle and thread fight.

But as the OP says, "the villain fights using the chain and hook". Which is true in Legend of the Swordsman and absent here.

Oh haha, you're right. It was quite late when I wrote this :p
